# Collect an email address with Stripe

Tags: node.js, email, stripe-payments

I'm following https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment and it works.

I need to collect a customer email address.  I am using the client-server integration, as I believe this is necessary to support a dynamic price, set with the following code:

```
router.post("/create-payment-intent", async (req, res) => {
    const stripe = require("stripe")("redacted");
  const { items } = req.body;
  // Create a PaymentIntent with the order amount and currency
  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: calculateOrderAmount(items),
    currency: "usd"
  });
  res.send({
    clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret
  });
});
```

I've been very confused by the documentation.  (I've previously used PayPal for payments, which has its own issues.)

How can I collect an email address, as part of the Stripe checkout process?

Could someone point me at the correct page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd collect the email address yourself, using a HTML element on your checkout page. You then have the choice to create a [Stripe customer with this information](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create) and [pass that into your PaymentIntent creation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-customer) if you wish to reuse the customer later. Or you can just pass the email address in the `receipt_email` field when [creating the PaymentIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-receipt_email).

Comment: That's a pity, I'd hoped to have a Stripe-styled and handled field, such as on the "Donate $5" from https://stripe-samples.github.io/github-pages-stripe-checkout/

Comment: Those buttons aren't part of stripe.js. They are regular buttons that call stripe.js when clicked. If you inspect them you'll see that the CSS comes from the page, not from Stripe.

Comment: I can't make sense of this answer. How am I supposed to pass the email from the client side into my `PaymentIntent`, when I have to create a payment intent before I can load the fields on the front end? This makes sense if I have people registering on my site before hand, but if I want to have "anonymous customers" whilst still sending them an electronic copy of their receipt (forcing email to be a required field), I am not going to have a full page dedicated to them filling out their email, relaying that to my server, creating the payment intent, then redirecting them to the checkout page.

Comment: Bear in mind that my answer is now 3 years old. Things have changed a bit in that time. These days Stripe does provide an email field solution, although you can still use a regular `input` field if you prefer: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/elements/link-authentication-element

Since the recommended path is now that you create the PaymentIntent on page load (and before you load the PaymentElement), you can pass in `receipt_email` when confirming the PaymentIntent with Stripe.js. You can see an example of how to do that here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart